# Why is React Router not routing to a nested route?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am using `react-router-dom` version 6.11.2 for my front-end routing in my App.js file:

```
import "./App.css";
import {
  Route,
  RouterProvider,
  createBrowserRouter,
  createRoutesFromElements,
} from "react-router-dom";
import RootLayout from "./layouts/RootLayout";
import { UserContextProvider } from "./store/user-context";
import NotFound404 from "./components/Utility/NotFound404";
import Login from "./pages/general/Login";
import CreateUser from "./pages/general/CreateUser";

const clientRouter = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <>
      <Route path="/auth" element={<Login />}>
        <Route path="new-user" element={<CreateUser />} />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/" element={<RootLayout />} errorElement={<NotFound404 />}>
        {/* children routes */}
      </Route>

    </>
  )
);

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <UserContextProvider>
        <RouterProvider router={clientRouter}></RouterProvider>
      </UserContextProvider>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

However, when routing to `"/auth/new-user"`, the `CreateUser` component is not rendered.

Login:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import styles from "./Login.module.css";
import Title from "../../components/Layout/Title";

const Login = () => {
  console.log("login rendered");
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    console.log("Login submitted:", email, password);

    try {
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/login", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify({ email, password }),
      });

      if (response.ok) {
        //do something
      } else {
        //do something
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      //handle error
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Title />
      <div className={styles.loginForm}>
        <h2>Login</h2>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <div className={styles.formControl}>
            <label htmlFor="email">Email:</label>
            <input
              type="email"
              id="email"
              value={email}
              onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
              required
            />
          </div>
          <div className={styles.formControl}>
            <label htmlFor="password">Password:</label>
            <input
              type="password"
              id="password"
              value={password}
              onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
              required
            />
          </div>
          <button type="submit">Login</button>
        </form>
        <Link to={"new-user"}>Create New User</Link>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

CreateUser:

```
import styles from "./Login.module.css";
import react, { useState } from "react";

const CreateUser = () => {
  console.log("create user rendered");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [confirmPassword, setConfirmPassword] = useState("");

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    try {
      // Validation: Check if passwords match
      if (password !== confirmPassword) {
        // Handle password mismatch error
        return;
      }

      // Perform new user registration logic here

      console.log("New user registered:", email, password);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      // Handle error
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className={styles.loginForm}>
        <h2>Create New User</h2>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <div className={styles.formControl}>
            <label htmlFor="email">Email:</label>
            <input
              type="email"
              id="email"
              value={email}
              onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
              required
            />
          </div>
          <div className={styles.formControl}>
            <label htmlFor="password">Password:</label>
            <input
              type="password"
              id="password"
              value={password}
              onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
              required
            />
          </div>
          <div className={styles.formControl}>
            <label htmlFor="confirmPassword">Confirm Password:</label>
            <input
              type="password"
              id="confirmPassword"
              value={confirmPassword}
              onChange={(e) => setConfirmPassword(e.target.value)}
              required
            />
          </div>
          <button type="submit">Register</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default CreateUser;
```

All my other front-end routing that is defined after the `"/auth"` route, including the children routes work without any issues, and when I define the `"/new-user"` route as an absolute path sibling to the `"/auth"` route, `CreateUser` renders properly. Is there some specific issue with nesting routes that I am not seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like `CreateUser` to be rendered as a nested child route of the `Login` component on `"/auth"` then `Login` ***necessarily*** should render an `Outlet` component for the nested route(s) to render its/their `element` content to.

See [Layout Routes](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts#layout-routes) and [Outlets](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts#outlets) for more details.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  Link,
  Outlet, // <-- Import Outlet component
  useNavigate
} from "react-router-dom";
import styles from "./Login.module.css";
import Title from "../../components/Layout/Title";

const Login = () => {
  ...

  return (
    <>
      <Title />
      <div className={styles.loginForm}>
        <h2>Login</h2>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          ...
        </form>
        <Link to={"new-user"}>Create New User</Link>
      </div>
      <Outlet /> {/* <-- Render Outlet for nested routes */}
    </>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

If you happen to instead only want `Login` and `CreateUser` to be "sibling" components, each rendered on their own page then demote the `Login` component down to a nested route.

```
const clientRouter = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <>
      <Route path="/auth"> {/* <-- Renders an Outlet by default */}
        <Route
          index {/* <-- Renders on parent's path, e.g. "/auth"  */}
          element={<Login />}
        />
        <Route path="new-user" element={<CreateUser />} />
      </Route>
      <Route
        path="/"
        element={<RootLayout />}
        errorElement={<NotFound404 />}
      >
        {/* children routes */}
      </Route>
    </>
  )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `clientRouter` should be like this :

```
import { BrowserRouter as  Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';

//rest code is same
const clientRouter = createBrowserRouter(
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/auth" element={<Login />}>
      <Route path="new-user" element={<CreateUser />} />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/" element={<RootLayout />} errorElement={<NotFound404 />} />
  </Routes>
);
```

Comment: Just FYI (1) You might not want to render a nested `BrowserRouter` like this, and (2) `createBrowserRouter` isn't imported and takes a `RouteObject[]` argument, not JSX.